# How to filter a list with another mutable vector in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, vector, filter

I am new to Haskell. I want to implement the following python program in Haskell.

```
a = [1,2,3,6,7,12,45,54,2,12,10]
b = [1,2,3,6,7,8]
c = [ i for i in b if a[i] % 2 == 0 ]
print c
```

I want `a` be a Data.Vector.Mutable in Haskell.
So I write something like

```
let a1 = fromList ([1,2,3,6,7,12,45,54,2,12,10] :: [Int])
let b = [1,2,3,6,7,8]
let c = [ i | i <- b, filter i a1 ] 
print c
```

However I have no idea about how to implement `filter` .
I know I should `x <- thaw a1` and `y <- read x i` then check y.
But how to assemble them together?

Comment: If you are new to Haskell you should *not* use mutation.  Tell us what you want to do, and maybe we can tell you how to do it without mutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that `a :: MVector s Int`, `b :: [Int]` and your result should be `c :: m [Int]`, where `m` is some monad, as we're using a mutable vector. Now, all we need is a fitting predicate:

```
-- evenVM :: PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) Int -> Int -> m Bool
evenVM v i = do
    if (M.length v) < i || i <= 0
      then return False
      else fmap even $ M.read v (i - 1)
```

`evenVM a` has type `PrimMonad m => Int -> m Bool`. As such, it can be used together with `filterM` (from `Control.Monad`), since every `PrimMonad` is also a `Monad`:

```
c = filterM (evenVM a) b
```

`thaw` isn't necessary if `a` really is a mutable vector. If `a` is a non-mutable vector, you can use `filter` and almost the same approach as above.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Vector's `zip` to index the elements and filter them accordingly.

```
import Data.Vector
import Prelude hiding(zip, filter, elem, map, length)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let a = fromList [1,2,3,6,7,12,45,54,2,12,10]
    let a' = fromList [0..(length a)]
    let b = fromList [1,2,3,6,7,8]
    let c = map snd $ filter (\(x,y) -> (y `elem` b) && x `mod` 2 == 0) (zip a a')
    print c
```

In ghci:

```
ghci > main
fromList [1,3,7,8]
```

Comment: `ifilter` provides you with the index while filtering.

Comment: a1 has to be Data.Vector.Mutable

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter in conjunction with map.

```
let a = [1,2,3,6,7,12,45,54,2,12,10]
    b = [1,2,3,6,7,8] :: [Int]
in filter even $ map (a !!)  b
```

If you need this from Vector you can add a couple of fromList:

```
import qualified Data.Vector V 

let a = V.fromList [1,2,3,6,7,12,45,54,2,12,10]
    b = V.fromList ([1,2,3,6,7,8] :: [Int])
in V.filter even $ V.map (a V.!)  b
```

And if you prefer the monadic version:

```
do
   a <- V.fromList [1,2,3,6,7,12,45,54,2,12,10]
   b <- V.fromList ([1,2,3,6,7,8] :: [Int])
   V.filter even (return (a V.! b))
```

Comment: OP wanted it for [Vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.11.0/docs/Data-Vector.html).

Comment: Updated with Vector addition. Which does not change a lot the statement.

Comment: This will filter all even elements in `a`, whose index is also in `b`. However, the original code wants the intersection between `b` and all indices of even elements in `a`.

Comment: Hi @mathk I need a1 to be Data.Vector.Mutable. Then you cannot use ! or !!.  And I didn't see filter function in Data.Vector.Mutable.